# how to check if al <li> tag consists an <img> tag and then run code if it exists

Tags: python, html, if-statement, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I undertook a web scraping project. There was a ul tag which consisted several li tags. My task was to print the content of the li tag only if the particular li tag consisted an img tag. i'm unable to do so. Dont know whats wrong with my code.
Here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#get the url of the site
url = 'https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/'

#make a GET request
req = requests.get(url)

#print stau code
print(req.status_code)

# parse the html document
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

device_list = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'device-name')
for device in device_list:
    device = device.find('div', class_ = 'text-center col-4')
    if device == 'none':
       model_name = device.find('div', class_ = 'col-8').text
        print(model_name)
    else:
        print('failure')
```

Comment: You don't appear to be checking for an `img` anywhere? (and not sure what you're trying to do with `if device == 'none'`...

Comment: Also `if device == 'none':` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `if device is None:`?

Comment: There are 81 listed devices on the menu left. Do you want to print only those which have the star icon next to them?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, i only want to print devices that have star icon next to them.

Comment: @buran i assinged device variable to find if there is an <img> tab in that particular <li> tag. So, if it cannot find an <img> tag it would print none. I was trying to check if the value of the variable device is equal to the string 'none'.

Comment: `device=='none'` will never be True

Comment: @buran i'm just learning python. Just experimenting stuff like web scraping using python. So...
Curious to know why device=='none' will never be true

Comment: Because if it didn't find a `div` tag with `class_ = 'text-center col-4'` it will yield `None`, not string `'none'`. And in this case you want to print `failure`. So it should be `if device is not None:`  or simply `if device:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you will find a `<img>` in your device object:

```
...
for device in device_list:
    if device.find('img'):
...
```

As an alternative you could select more specific to pick only these with `<img>` via `css selectors`:

```
for device in soup.select('li.device-name:has(img)'):
    print(device.find('div', class_ = 'col-8').text.strip())
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/'
req = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)

device_list = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'device-name')
for device in device_list:
    if device.find('img'):
        model_name = device.find('div', class_ = 'col-8').text.strip()
        print(model_name)
    else:
        print('failure')
```

##### Output

```
Google Pixel 3a/3a XL
failure
failure
failure
failure
failure
failure
Oneplus One
failure
Volla Phone
failure
failure
failure
failure
failure
Sony Xperia X (F5121 & F5122)
failure
...
```